# Need Help with Intro Animation

Tags: animation, light, smoke-simulation

I have some experience with Blender but not with animation or text. 
I'm looking to make an intro for my Youtube channel and have the vision but not the means. I've skimmed through some tutorials but the way my vision starts is too different for it to be much help.

My channel is very 3D print oriented so the intro goes as follows:

A 2D "E3D V6 print nozzle" moves along the screen, a bottom sliver of 2D text appears "from" it as it does. It moves up slightly and then along the screen in the opposite direction. The next up sliver of text appears "from" it as it does. This continues until the entire title is visible and "print nozzle" is at the top right. This takes 2-5 seconds.

Then the "print nozzle" disappears as a smoke spreads out from behind the text and into the surrounding screen. This decelerates. In the smoke are some "Bokeh lights" that follow the same action. This takes another 2-5 seconds.

Scene fades to black.

The text is a deep orange, the hot end a darker orange. The background is a very dark greenish blue, the smoke a bright neon blue and the bokeh lights a yellow.

**If you need help envisioning the scene take a look at my channel art [here](http://www.youtube.com/user/acrimoniousmirth).**

Any help is appreciated! I'm not sure where to start. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This... is a fairly detailed animation. Text animatics, smoke physics, compositing... Getting the smoke right alone can be a mission. But I can get you started with one non-fluid dynamics approach on the text:

Type out and position your text on one layer. Model some overlapping 'lines' of deep orange FDM-approved 'plastic' on a second layer. Position the nozzle on a third layer. Set up some masking planes for the plastic on a fourth layer. Animate the nozzle to zigzag over the text. As the nozzle moves, the appropriate mask moves to 'reveal' the plastic coming out.

In the compositor you'll want to set up your renderlayers and nodes in such a way that:

1. Masking planes hide the plastic. If you're working in Cycles you can do this fairly simply with the Mask Layer options for the masking planes.
2. Plastic layer pixels are visible if there are text pixels overlapping them. Stick an Alpha Over node between the Text and Plastic renderlayer outputs.

Again, this is a high-level overview and just one of many approaches you could use. Good luck :)